# Installing Composer on EC2 Linux Command Not Found

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, composer-php

I run the following commands to install the Composer:

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === 'aa96f26c2b67226a324c27919f1eb05f21c248b987e6195cad9690d5c1ff713d53020a02ac8c217dbf90a7eacc9d141d') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

Afterwards, when I run `composer`, I see that it is working. However, whenever I run `sudo composer`, I always receive

> Command Not Found.

The output ofthe `echo $PATH` is:

> /usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/aws/bin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin

What can I do to enable composer under sudo?

Answer (score 30):

First you need to SSH into your EC2 instance

`ssh -i ~/.ssh/<your_group_security>.pem ec2-user@<ec2-public-ip>`

Run below command on your EC2 instance

```
$ cd ~
$ sudo curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php
$ sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
```

Then you can run verify composer installation

`$ sudo composer install`

Answer (score 4):

If you can run composer "alone" then you should have composer installed in `/usr/local/bin/composer` so you can just link it to `/usr/bin/composer` with

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
```

and then run

```
sudo composer install
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer questions with limited info.

1. See if you can run `sudo composer.phar`. That is default name that composer installs itself into. Unless you rename it it by `mv /usr/local/bin/composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer`.
2. Run `ls /usr/local/bin/` to verify that composer got installed. Unless you are `root` you might not have correct permissions to access `/usr/local/bin`.

Answer (score -1):

Improving on the previous answers -
SSH into terminal & type :

```
$ cd ~
$ sudo curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php
$ sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
```

If you face an error that says: ***PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'proc_open(): fork failed - Cannot allocate memory' in phar***

```
/bin/dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap.1 bs=1M count=1024
/sbin/mkswap /var/swap.1
/sbin/swapon /var/swap.1
```

Comment: Please add some further explanation to your answer. How does this work any different than installing Composer listed in the other answers?

Comment: As stated in the answer if you install using the above methods you might encounter a memory exception, which is to be resolved by the second part of my answer. To give a holistic answer I have included all steps.